# Is there anyway to automatically select an autocomplete option if only one is shown using PyQT?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyqt

I'm trying to build a very time efficient way for users to store information. It uses a text interface that navigates the tree in which data is stored. I've had a UI built which works perfectly in all ways but one; it forces you to press the down arrow and then enter to autocomplete even if there is only one possible option given the substring entered.

For example, imagine the following are the options at a given node

```
Potato
Cabbage
Dave
Dove
Double
```

Once you've typed "P", the only thing you could possibly be referencing is "Potato". I'd like it to select potato, rather than force the user to press "down" and then "enter" in order to to select it. Is this possible using PyQT? If so, what options exist for implementation?

Comment: I have implemented what you want but I see a logic error. Let's say that the user pressed "P" and "Potato" was selected but then he wants to correct it so he deletes the "o" but as the autocomplete is applied then the "Potato" option will be shown as the only option so it will autocomplete so that the word could not be erased that way.

Comment: One can program a key which deletes an entire word to get around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the `modelReset`, `rowsInserted` and `rowsRemoved` signals from the `completionModel()` and then check if the number of rows is 1 to select the row and then hide the popup.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QItemSelectionModel, QMetaObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCompleter, QLineEdit


class Completer(QCompleter):
    def init(self):
        self.completionModel().modelReset.connect(self._handle_count_changed)
        self.completionModel().rowsInserted.connect(self._handle_count_changed)
        self.completionModel().rowsRemoved.connect(self._handle_count_changed)

    def _handle_count_changed(self):
        if self.popup().isVisible() and self.completionModel().rowCount() == 1:
            self.popup().selectionModel().select(
                self.currentIndex(), QItemSelectionModel.Select
            )
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.popup(), "hide", Qt.QueuedConnection)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    words = ["Potato", "Cabbage", "Dave", "Dove", "Double"]

    lineedit = QLineEdit()
    lineedit.resize(320, lineedit.sizeHint().height())
    lineedit.show()

    completer = Completer(words, caseSensitivity=Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    completer.init()
    lineedit.setCompleter(completer)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in _handle_count_changed
NameError: name 'completer' is not defined"

I managed to get this to work by adding 
"
words = ["Potato", "Cabbage", "Dave", "Dove", "Double"] 
completer = Completer(words, caseSensitivity=Qt.CaseInsensitive)
"
just before definition of main

Comment: @JohnSalter Ooops, I already corrected it. See the update